# New versions of Xcode (3.2.5 and up) don't build distribution binaries by default

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, ipad

I found that while building in the new 3.2.5 Xcode I wasn't getting the distribution binaries. When I right clicked on the Products folder App no option for "Show in Finder" appeared.

I'm putting this for documentation purposes because I couldn't find an answer here but I figured it out in the end.

Answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Build menu and select Build and Archive. This will open up Organizer which will bring up a new screen from a section called Archived Applications. This keeps a track of all the bianary builds. From here you can Validate and Submit your App. You no longer have to zip the file and upload with Application Loader.

It's interesting that it lets you validate without having to upload. I haven't played with this a lot so there might be other neat things about it.